# Is this reflexive?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I would like to know whether the following "$\sim$" is reflexive and/or symmetric or not according to the following definition:

> Suppose $\sim$ is defined on the set of the integers as follows : $a\sim b$ iff $ab ≤ a|b|$

How do I proceed to solve this problem? Please help. Thanks!

Comment: For reflexive: What happens when $a$ is negative?

Comment: Hint: Can you figure out exactly when does $ab\leq a|b|$ hold?

Comment: What is the $n$ in the title and statement of the problem ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I think it represents integers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prove reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity for the following relation?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2001466/how-to-prove-reflexivity-symmetry-and-transitivity-for-the-following-relation)

Answer (score 2):

A *relation* $R$ is reflexive when :

> for all $x : xRx$.

Thus $\sim$ is reflexive **iff** for all $a : aa ≤ a|a|$.

Consider now $a := -2$ : $aa= (-2)(-2) = 4 > -4 = (-2)(|-2|)$.

Conclusion : not reflexive.

---

For symmetry :

> is it true that, if $ab \le a|b|$, then $ba \le |b|a$ ?

In general, for $a,b < 0$ we have that $ab > 0$ while $a|b| < 0$ ($+ \times - = -$) and thus $ab > a|b|$.

Also, for $a,b \ge 0$ we have that $a|b| = ab = |b|a$. Thus $ab \le a|b|$ and also $ba \le |b|a$.

Conclusion, we have only to take care of the cases : $a > 0$ and $b < 0$ and $a < 0$ and $b > 0$.

Comment: Is it not $a : a|a| ≤ a|a|$?

Comment: @kunjimamu - in your question you have written $aa \le a|a|$...