# How to prove reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity for the following relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

I would like to know how to prove reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity for $\sim$ according to the following definition:

> Suppose $\sim$ is defined on the set of the integers as follows : $a\sim b$ iff $ab ≤ a|b|$

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: Is $aa\leq a|a|$?  always?  or are there examples of $a$ such that $aa>a|a|$?  Now... if $ab\leq a|b|$ does that mean that $ba\leq b|a|$?  always?  or are there examples of $a$ and $b$ such that despite $ab\leq a|b|$ that you have $ba>b|a|$?

Comment: Your question is wrong, $\sim$ isn't reflexive. Just look at copper.hat counterexample.

Comment: So we can give a counter example to disprove a statement? @Charter

Comment: @kunjimamu of course.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you *would* prove it by showing:

1) Reflexive: $a \sim a$.

2) Symmetric: If $a\sim b$, then $b\sim a$.

3) Transitive: If $a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$, then $a\sim c$.

However, you're going to have trouble, because it's not true for your relation. Note that $-1 \sim -1$ is **false**, because $-1\cdot -1 \leq -1\lvert -1 \rvert$ is false.

Comment: For this: −1⋅−1≤−1|−1|. Are you saying that the reflexivity  fails?

Comment: @kunjimamu That's right - the left hand side becomes 1 and the right hand side becomes -1. It is not true that $1 \leq -1$, so this relation is not reflexive.

Answer (score 0):

If $-1 \sim -1$ then $1 \le -1$.

In other words, the relation is **not** reflexive.