# How to prove the symmetrical relation for the following statement?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I would like to know how to prove the symmetrical relation for $\sim$ according to the following definition:

> Suppose $\sim$ is defined on the set of the integers as follows : $a\sim b$ iff $ab ≤ a|b|$

Please explain to me. Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2000968/is-this-reflexive and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2001466/how-to-prove-reflexivity-symmetry-and-transitivity-for-the-following-relation

Comment: Why does this keep getting asked? And why is it always tagged "wave equation"?

Comment: @carmichael561 I would revert it back to you: why does this question is not being answered?

Comment: Both of the questions linked have perfectly fine answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT : Simplest approach is to make cases. There are just 4 cases a,b>0, a>0 b<0, a,b<0 and a<0 b>0.

You will see that not all cases are possible if the condition is true, and for the remaining cases, the symmetric relationship b~a is also true.

Let me know if this is not sufficient and I will write it out! Hope it helps!